# Navigate to another page without executing code next to it

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I have written a custom HttpClientHandler to set the token in each HTTP request and to handle 401 responses.

Here is the helper class.

```
public class CustomHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
    {
        private readonly ISyncLocalStorageService localStorageService;
        private readonly NavigationManager navigationManager;

        public CustomHttpClientHandler(ISyncLocalStorageService localStorageService, NavigationManager NavigationManager)
        { 
            this.localStorageService = localStorageService;
            navigationManager = NavigationManager;
        }

        protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var token = localStorageService.GetItem<string>(Auth.Token.ToString());
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is after navigating to the login page. I want this method to exit from here and not execute the return line.

What I know is I can throw a custom exception and catch it globally and then redirect from there. But just to know, is there any other way for it?

```
if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
  navigationManager.NavigateTo("login"); // i want to exit code from here
}

return response; // and not want to return response.
```

What's happening is even though I redirect it to the login page it returns the response and my razor component will throw null reference exception because of the below line, as I am reading the response and returning it after deserializing it, which returns null.

```
var stringResult = await httpResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOutput>(stringResult);
```

What I can do is to check everywhere after getting an HTTP response for null, but I want to handle it generically.

Comment: exception is the way to go